# How does Microsoft Razor Syntax run server side code without exposing it to the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how Razor syntax works.

It is my understanding that it will allow you to embed server-side code directly into the page, but it keeps all of that from the client even though the client can interact with it.

I'm used to ASP.net web views and things of that nature - does the Razor syntax essentially do postbacks and all of the code is contained within the page, or is the way that the client interacts with the server-side code fundamentally different?

If this is too open-ended, please leave me comments as to how to focus the question more.  I fear I don't yet understand enough to make finely-focused questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Just like old ASP, just like PHP, the server-side framework processes the code and emits the result as a page to the client.  It doesn't do any post-backs or conduct any kind of magic, it simply processes the server-side components resulting in a page to send to the client.  Write an ASP.NET project, open it in a browser, look at the page source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding:

**1. How Razor syntax works:**

You can see the Razor is similar to the scriplet in Web Form. For example, you want to get the `Name` of the `Human` class, in `.cshtml` file, you write:

```
<div>Name is @Model.Name</div>
```

And in `aspx`, you write:

```
<div>Name is <%= Human.Name %></div>
```

Both Razor and scriplet will be processed before returning the `HTML` files to client. Follow the above example, if you view the source of your HTML web page, you will see (Forte is just an example):

```
<div>Name is Forte</div>
```

Because the code was processed, so, what the client see is the HTML result only.

**2.How do clients interact with server?**

In Web Form, when you want to go to server (like handle `click` button event), you can generate the function to call by set `OnClickListener` for the button, and everything is done automatically for you.

However, in MVC.NET, you have to do it through Ajax call, or put your button in a `<form>`.

If you have any question, feel free to let me know :)

Comment: I guess that's one of my hang-ups, Razor allows you to get around Ajax by doing more javaScript-like things itself then?  It goes back to the server still for processing, but the page understands that this is not a full postback and is simply running sections of the C# (or what-have-you) code?

Comment: What do you mean in "JavaScript-like things"? All Razor code will be processed and turn into string, then return to clients. That's why in `.cshtml` you write: `<script>var name = @Model.Name</script>` and in `HTML` source, you see `<script>var name = Forte</script>`

Answer (score 3):

mvc runs all that stuff server side and provides the client with the resulting html/javascript generation.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have this in a view

```
@{ var var1 =   "Hello World"; }
<p>The value of var1 is: @var1</p>
```

Everything happens on the server

When a user is requesting this page the server gets the text above and sends it to the view engine.

Then the server runs the text line by line and "compiles" it.

Then the server snds the result back to the user:

```
The value of var1 is: Hello World
```

If the user makes a view source he will see only:

```
<p>The value of myMessage is: Hello World</p>
```

So the user on the client writes a simple URL , and the result he is getting is ONLY the line above.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it compiles the view like any other csharp/vb.net file.  However, it does it on-the-fly (the first time you hit it, and the underlying file hasn't changed).

If you want to see what the generated code looks like, take a look at https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator  This allows you to actually generate the same code as part of MSbuild and deploy it.